# Are CSS combined size, scale and depth combined before interpolation?

Tags: html, css, browser, rendering

When applying css rules that are affecting the visual size and subpixels of an image, for example:

Source image 400x400 px;

- Applying a css width/height rule
- Adding a scale factor
- Adding a translate3d Z factor with perspective

Are all these rules combined into a single matrix when processing the image rendering or are these calculated one after the other?

In other terms, Should I care about pixel preservation?

Comment: er... what? are you trying to write a browser? I can't tell what you're trying to achieve here. What is "pixel preservation". Worked in IT/design for 25 years - never heard of it. Anyway, I'd check the CSS spec for this but it sounds like something that would be implementation dependant.

Comment: I think one after another

Comment: Thanks, no, I'm not trying to write a browser, I'm just wondering if I may set a size for a responsive design, then use a scale hover afterwards, or if I should consider recalculating size and modify this one instead, pixel preservation is just a term like photoshop does with smart objects, always calculates from the source, not the last state.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Chrome, at least, CSS's `width` and `height` property are classed as "layout" and CSS's `transform` property is classed as "composite".

If we refer to [this article](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/speed/high-performance-animations/) we're shown this screenshot of how Chrome orders its CSS rendering events:

[image: Chrome Timeline Event Example]

So to answer your question as best as I can: Layout is calculated before Painting, which is calculated before the Composite Layers.

Also linked in the above article is [this Google Docs spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/pub?key=0ArK1Uipy0SbDdHVLc1ozTFlja1dhb25QNGhJMXN5MXc&single=true&gid=0&output=html) which tells us which styles relate to which CSS rendering event.

Comment: This gives an approximate idea, now we still don't know if the transform phase is based on the source data or on the already painted data...